# Site clone script running for hours

Tags: sxa, item-clones

I have started cloning a `SXA` site but it's shows "running script..." on UI.

[image]

I checked few things

1. Checked logs, found this line `Job ended: SPE - "Clone Site" - sitecore\Admin (units processed: )`
2. Checked `/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx` there is no Running or Queued jobs.

Can I consider it done without any update on UI or shall I wait?
How would I know the progress of the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to tell (at least for `Clone-Site` script) what's the current status.

This issue might be caused by [known issue in SPE](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/965).
It often happens when you run a script in CE and switch to other browser tabs. It affects only UI, backend can still work fine.

What I would suggest you to do is simply do a quick test and compare number of items for your source and destination sites.

Here is a PowerShell snippet.

`(gci -Path 'site_path' -Recurse).Count`

If number of items is the same for both sites you can safety assume that script finished without any issues.

Comment: Does this count related items also? Like in media, theme, form etc?

Comment: No, `gci` stands for `Get-ChildItem`. So it will count only child items of your site. 
You will have to validate tenant templates, media folders separately.